# How can I use skfuzzy in Django?

Tags: python, django, fuzzy-logic, skfuzzy

I have created a Django project and I want to implement a simple fuzzy logic with three inputs and one output.

However, when I import `skfuzzy` in Django views and reload the page, I get a Gateway Timeout error after 2 minutes (even without any implementation, just importing `skfuzzy`).

I have run `pip3 install scikit-fuzzy` in the project virtual environment, and everything seems to be working fine.

The code runs without a problem in the terminal, but it doesn't work in the Django project. Why is this happening?